# Why ssh.service doesn’t start automatically during boot despite being enabled by systemd?

Tags: systemd, startup, sshd, systemd-unit

I’m using Debian 11 on a Raspberry Pi 4 (image found [here](https://raspi.debian.net/tested-images/)).
sshd is properly configured (I only edited /etc/ssh/sshd_config, the rest is completely fresh from system installation) and works correctly when I start it manually. However it doesn’t start automatically by systemd at boot. **sudo systemctl status sshd** returns this:

```
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
```

There is nothing related to ssh in journalctl’s output.

This is the content of **/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service**:

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenBSD Secure Shell server
Documentation=man:sshd(8) man:sshd_config(5)
After=network.target auditd.service
ConditionPathExists=!/etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/ssh
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/sshd -t
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartPreventExitStatus=255
Type=notify
RuntimeDirectory=sshd
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0755

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=sshd.service
```

The file *sshd_not_to_be_run* does not exist. *network.target* is active. I also installed auditd just for troubleshoot and it successfully starts automatically, but ssh.service is still dead after reboot.

I run out of ideas…

---

UPDATE:

I just discovered that a sshd process spawns on every connection demand. It is managed by systemd itself and it’s clearly printed in the journal when some foreign computers try to connect to mine:

```
oct. 30 13:09:30 RaspServeur systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server per-connection daemon (117.68.2.55:45784).
░░ Subject: L'unité (unit) ssh@4-192.168.1.2:22-117.68.2.55:45784.service a terminé son démarrage
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ L'unité (unit) ssh@4-192.168.1.2:22-117.68.2.55:45784.service a terminé son démarrage, avec le résultat done.
oct. 30 13:09:30 RaspServeur audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj==unconfined msg='unit=ssh@4-192.168.1.2:22-117.68.2.55:45784 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" ho>
oct. 30 13:09:33 RaspServeur sshd[1861]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
oct. 30 13:09:33 RaspServeur sshd[1861]: Connection closed by 117.68.2.55 port 45784
oct. 30 13:09:33 RaspServeur systemd[1]: ssh@4-192.168.1.2:22-117.68.2.55:45784.service: Succeeded.
░░ Subject: Unit succeeded
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ The unit ssh@4-192.168.1.2:22-117.68.2.55:45784.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
oct. 30 13:09:33 RaspServeur audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj==unconfined msg='unit=ssh@4-192.168.1.2:22-117.68.2.55:45784 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hos>
```

It’s like a parallel installation of sshd exists with a default configuration. My own configuration with settings like a specific port number to use can’t work without starting manually the sshd.service. But I can successfully connect to that shadow sshd with default port, and *systemctl status sshd* still reports a dead service…

The situation becomes creepy, I’m now two fingers away to erase the SD card and install an image of another distribution with less pre-configuration.

Comment: Have you enabled SSH via the ```raspi-config``` command? Take a look at the following article. https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-6-using-ssh/enabling-ssh

Comment: I’m using a true Debian image, not Raspberry Pi OS. So I don’t have raspi-config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could this be the same issue as the one the asker of [question #442181](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442181) had? I.e. sshd fails to start at boot because the interface/address it wants to bind to isn't ready yet. You mention that you've specified a non-standard port for the server socket, have you also specified a particular network interface and/or IP address?

I don't know why systemd instead starts a per-connection daemon that uses
the standard configuration, though. It might be part of the default system configuration, as you suggest. In [question #507705](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/507705) they talk about systemd "socket activation", which apparently is the feature that provides per-connection service spawning. Look for a systemd unit file named `ssh.socket`. You can use `man systemd.socket` to get information about how the feature works.

Edit: You should be able to use `systemctl status ssh.socket` to check whether systemd's SSH server socket is enabled.

Comment: Indeed, there is a ssh.socket unit implemented, with a line **Conflicts=ssh.service** inside the definition file. So I disabled this unit, rebooted, then my sshd.service started automatically as expected. Thanks for pointing me to the culprit.

Comment: Too bad that the **systemctl status ssh\*** returns only the ssh.service unit, not ssh.socket… Instead I would have discovered it and diagnosed the issue much earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If you start sshd manually, systemd will not register that as started, so it makes sense that systemctl shows nothing. Each sshd really is a listening process and after a connection has been made, a separate process dealing with this connection is forked. If you `ps` there will be multiple sshd processes reflecting this. Ff you kill the sshd-listener, the other sshd processes that are handling connections will still be alive.

If you start sshd and do a systemctl start sshd. That's the equivalent of starting 2 sshds, which can block if they all try to use the same port.

Hope that helps